# Нужна помощь в парсинге на python библиотека selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Задача открыть в поиске каждую вкладку, открываю по TAG_NAME 'h3' но есть еще по середине заголовок с этим тегом и как попадает на него процесс выкидывает ошибку. Как добавить этот заголовок в исключение или чтоб как на него натыкался проходил мимо. Побывал открывать каждую ссылку по классу,не открывает. Подскажите кодом

```
button_links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,'h3')
for i in range(len(button_links)):
    button_links[i].click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.back()
```

Comment: html разметку покажите, чтобы было понятней, что происходит и как помочь

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, не хватало счетчика ссылок поэтому ошибка была.

```
links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'LC20lb.MBeuO.DKV0Md')
for i in range(len(links)):
    links[i].click()
    i+=1
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(3)
```